# Choosing Priors

Tags: bayesian

Trying to figure out how to choose a prior for mu:

Let y represent your heart rate when you get mad. Sadly, you have been getting mad a lot lately, so you have a lot of data. To learn your mean, mad-heart-rate, you model the data by

$yi|µ,φ ∼ Normal(µ,φ^−1)$

$µ ∼ ?$

$φ ∼ Gamma(.01,.01)$

State three possible priors that you could use for this model of the mean µ and why or when you would use them.

I'm thinking along the lines of conjugate priors and Jeffreys priors (those are the only ones I know), but I'm unsure. I also don't know how to explain my reasoning for choosing these priors.

Comment: It sounds like this question may require the self study tag.

Comment: Can your heart rate be negative?

Comment: Any prior is acceptable, the Bayesian analysis is relative to this prior measure.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to remember what prior distribution represents.

Prior distribution represent *a priori* information on the parameter of interest.

So, for instance do you have 'vague' information about what the *mad-mean* heart rate should be? Then use a **reference prior**. This could be a Uniform for example, or a Gamma. For instance distributions that do not concentrate large probability densities over an specific region.

However your choosen prior should be consistent with the parameter you want to estimate. In your case, heart rates can't be negative or zero (or you will be dead).